# Get Unique Email Identifier from GMail URL

Tags: javascript, regex, gmail

At the moment, I am coding an Google Chrome extension (in Javascript) which interfaces with GMail. The extension needs to know the unique email identifier that is present at the end of every GMail URL.

> Eg. https://mail.google.com/mail/#inbox/**11a4ac0cg2bc3330**
>         https://mail.google.com/mail/#label/Archived+Emails/**11a4c8b472b03c87**

What would be the best way to get this unique identifier using Javascript (through regex or otherwise, preferably in a function like this:

> function getIdentifier(URL){
>                  [Insert your magic here]
>                  return ID;
>              }

Thanks,

DLiKS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is based on your samples provided, if you're assured of the format, you can use [`.substirng()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/substring) and [`.lastIndexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/lastIndexOf), like this:

```
function getIdentifier(URL){
  return URL.substring(URL.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
}
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/wb8uR/1/), this keeps it pretty simple, find the last `/`, move over one to exclude the `/` itself, take the rest of the string.

Comment: Why didn't I think of this?! Thanks a lot!